# code for shift add unit

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

i write the code for shift adder unit....but i didnt get correct result...here i cant ble to post ckt for the same...i think clk synchronization problem in there

```
 module shift_adder_8a(clk,,j0,j7,s089,s075,s050,s018);
input clk;
input [2:0] j0,j7;
 reg[3:0]z0;
output reg[10:0]s089,s075,s050,s018;
reg[6:0] o0,p0;

always@(posedge clk )
begin
 z0 <= j0-j7;
 o0 <= (z0<<3)+z0;
 p0 <=  (z0<<4)+o0;
 s089 <= (z0<<6)+p0;
 s075 <= (p0<<1)+p0;
 s050 <= (p0<<1);
 s018 <= (o0<<1);

 end
endmodule
```

Comment: Can you at leas explain what the signals mean? What is the required functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not "get correct result", I'm assuming you mean the results are coming delayed.

Try moving the `z0`,`o0`,`p0` assignments into a combinational block:

```
always @* begin
 z0 = j0-j7;
 o0 = (z0<<3)+z0;
 p0 = (z0<<4)+o0;
end
always@(posedge clk )
begin
 s089 <= (z0<<6)+p0;
 s075 <= (p0<<1)+p0;
 s050 <= (p0<<1);
 s018 <= (o0<<1);
end
```